# Is there a way to console.log all event occuring inside Backbone Marionette ItemView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a backbone marionette view in which i have defined many events.
I want to store a log for any event which is occuring inside my itemview. I dont want to write function calling for my audit data on every data, instead i had like to override backbone marionette events method so that it is applied on all my ItemViews.

I tried using:

```
var originalTrigger = Backbone.Events.trigger;
Backbone.Events.trigger = function(){
  console.log("Event Triggered:");
  console.log(arguments.join(", "));
  originalTrigger.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

But it doesnt do anything for me. Please help

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

If you check the Backbone source you'll see things like this:

```
_.extend(Model.prototype, Events, {
```

where `Model` and `Events` are local aliases for `Backbone.Model` and `Backbone.Events` respectively. That means that the methods from `Backbone.Events` will have been copied to the model, collection, and view prototypes before you have a chance to wrap `Backbone.Events.trigger` with your auditing.

You'll want to wrap all four `trigger`s after Backbone is loaded but before anything else (including Marionette) is loaded. Something like this:

```
(function() {
    var trigger = Backbone.Events.trigger;
    var wrapper = function() {
        console.log("Event Triggered:");
        console.log(arguments.join(", "));
        trigger.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    Backbone.Model.prototype.trigger      = wrapper;
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.trigger = wrapper;
    Backbone.View.prototype.trigger       = wrapper;
})();
```

after `<script src="backbone.js">` but before `<script src="backbone.marionette.js">` should do the trick.

Comment: I am using Require.js to load my dependencies. Backbone and Marionette both are being loaded through Require.config file.

I tried adding your function after loading dependencies but gave me an error object#object has no method join.

Comment: I don't know how you'd do this with require.js, the technique should be the same though, you just need to get your hands on `Backbone` before Marionette does. That error is meaningless without context.

Comment: The method did worked before including the marionette. However i still couldnt found a way to do it with require.js
I ended with writing custom code on every event.